# How can I encrypt in php in this way?

Tags: php, base64, md5, pack

What function should I use to encrypt a password in this way?

```
rtrim(base64_encode (pack ('H*', md5 ('123456'))), '=')
```

Example:

```
4QrcOUm6Wau+VuBX8g+IPg = 123456
```

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. That *hashes* (irreversible) it does not *encrypt* (reversible). Is it not PHP already?

Comment: Yes it is PHP, I'm also not sure what does the OP mean...

Comment: I just want to know how can I use that code to encrypt a password, I don't know how to write it down.

Comment: Your question is not clear nor do you explain what the issue is.

Comment: The issue is I want to encrypt in that way a password, and I don't know how.

Comment: you just wrote how, if you want to md5 hash a string you just use `$myHashedString = md5($OriginalString);` this is why nobody understands what you want, you have the answer to your question in your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

there is multiple way to encrypt a password.

If fact you should hash a password it's better.

To do that, very simple  use sha1 or md5 hashing methods.

```
   $var =  sha1('1234');
   echo $var;
```

or

```
$var = md5('1234');
echo $var;
```

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you Anselme, I made: <?php

$var =  rtrim(base64_encode (pack ('H*', md5 ('123456'))), '=');
echo $var;

?>